# Map array with initial letter in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I wish to group a word list in an array with the initial letter.

```
function alpha($str) {
    $result[substr($str,0,1)] = $str;
    return $result;
}

$a = ['abc','cde','frtg','acf'];
$b = array_map('alpha', $a);
print_r($b);
```

What I need:

```
Array
(
    [a] => abc,acf
    [c] => cde
    [f] => frtg
)
```

What I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => abc
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [c] => cde
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [f] => frtg
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => acf
        )
)
```

Comment: [a] => abc,acf , this is not possible. You can add only one value to a key, otherwise, you have to use multidimensional array like a => array(abc,acf)

Comment: Yes, It Just to explain the concept. your Is the correct syntax

Comment: hi, I have added my answer. Check if it's working for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that :

```
$answer = [];
$a = ['abc','cde','frtg','acf'];

foreach($a as $word){
    $key = substr($word,0,1);
    
    if (isset($answer[$key])){
        $answer[$key] .= "," . $word;
    } else {
        $answer[$key] = $word;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a variable `$c` and loop over arrays of array using two *foreach* and group by *alphabet*...

```php
function alpha($str) {
    $result[substr($str,0,1)] = $str;
    return $result;
}
$a = ['abc','cde','frtg','acf'];
$b = array_map('alpha', $a);
#print_r($b);

$c = [];
foreach ($b as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($c[$key])){
            $c[$key]=$value;
        }else{
            $c[$key].= "," . $value;
        }
    }
}
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($c);
```

*Outupt:*

```
Array
(
    [a] => abc,acf
    [c] => cde
    [f] => frtg
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `array_map` maps to the original indexes but you want new indexes and an altered array, if there are more values with the same initial character. Therefore `array_map` don't work for you. You could create your new array this way:

```
$a = ['abc','cde','frtg','acf'];
$b = Array();
$c = Array();

foreach( $a as $v )
{
    // multidimensional array
    $b[substr($v,0,1)][] = $v;

    // comma separated string
    $c[substr($v,0,1)] = (isset($c[substr($v,0,1)])) ? 
                         $c[substr($v,0,1)].",$v" : $v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first character can also be multibyte Unicode such as ° or €, [mb_substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-substr.php) must be used! Solution with foreach:

```
$result = [];
$a = ['abc','€de','frtg','acf'];

foreach($a as $word){
    $key = mb_substr($word,0,1);
    $result[$key] = array_key_exists($key,$result) 
       ? ($result[$key].",".$word)
       : $word
    ;
}
```

Solution with [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$result = array_reduce($a,function($carry,$item){
  $key = mb_substr($item,0,1);
  $carry[$key] = array_key_exists($key,$carry) ? ($carry[$key].",".$item) : $item;
  return $carry;
  },[]);

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 'abc,acf',
  '€' => '€de',
  'f' => 'frtg',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is to store each word into arrays according to its first letter. In this case, the multidimensional array is the right choice.

```js
$array = ['abc','cde','frtg','acf'];
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $v){
  $letter = substr($v,0,1);
  if(!isset($new_array[$letter])) {$new_array[$letter] = array();}
  array_push($new_array[$letter], $v);
}

print_r($new_array);
```